# Tree Map Generation in Python

Tags: python, java

I have a object
{"abc":123}
I have written a simple Java Function to convert this object

```
public String getObjectPayload(Map<String, Object> paramMap) {
    Map<String, Object> sortedMap = new TreeMap(paramMap);
    sortedMap.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
    return StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(sortedMap.values(), "|");
}
```

I am facing issue when I am implementing the same logic in python

My desired result is a final string from this object, Java function is giving me the correct results, the interpretation is
"abc|123"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.join()` with a generator expression:

```py
>>> d = {'abc': 123}
>>> "|".join("|".join(map(str, t)) for t in d.items())

'abc|123'
```

or

```py
>>> d = {"abc": 123, "def": 456}
>>> "|".join("|".join(map(str, t)) for t in d.items())

'abc|123|def|456'
```

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension it is also possible to achieve the intended result:

```
d = {"abc":123}
'|'.join([str(item) for value in d.items() for item in value])
# Result:
'abc|123'
```